# simple docker run target in goland can't find package main

Tags: docker, ssh, goland

I'm trying to do some testing with go1.18 and thought I'd give docker run targets a shot from within goland Build #GO-213.6461.23, built on December 16, 2021.

It's simple hello world application and I'm trying to use the docker image setup. It seems to have found the docker server and the docker image OK, but when I try and set the run target to this config, I get a warning that it cannot find package main.

I've plonked in a screen shot of the config. It's got me tossed.

[image: goland config]

The error message is displayed in the screen shot above at the bottom.

The code is a simple hello wordld

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var test string
    test = "Hi there"
    fmt.Println(test)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

which of course runs fine if run on the local machine.

The run target is configured as follows
[image]

That should be enough to reproduce the set up I'm trying to use.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], or the actual error message?  What's in the Dockerfile and the application code?

Comment: A small comment: `main` package should exist in your project locally and GoLand will transfer it to Docker container, build and then run it.

Comment: Updated detail in the question. The error was showing in the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the module name from *go.mod* file. According to your screenshot, it seems that your *Package path* should be `awesomeProject` instead of `main`.

From GoLand documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/running-applications.html#create-go-build-configuration):

> Package path: a full import path of the package that you want to compile (for example, github.com/gorilla/mux). This field is available only when you select the Package run kind.

Alternatively, you can run your application using gutter icons and GoLand creates run configuration with the correct *Package path* automatically.

[image]

After that, you can invoke *Run | Edit Configurations* and select Run Target to Docker one.

Comment: Thanks @s0xzwasd. I have the app running locally, change the target as you suggested, and now have a different error:  package awsomeProject is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/awsomeProject)   . Closer perhaps :)

Comment: @PeterNunn, make sure that Go modules integration is enabled under _File | Settings | Go | Go modules_, _go.mod_ file exists in your project and _Index entire GOPATH_ is disabled under _File | Settings | Go | GOPATH_. After that, re-create your run configuration.

Comment: sadly no change. I did turn off index entire GOPATH, and tried with and without the use GOPATH from system env flag, but no joy (I'm assuming by re-create your run config, you mean re-do the run target setup (ie, pull image?).

Comment: @PeterNunn, please, share a project structure. By re-creating run config, I meant delete previous ones (_Run | Edit Configurations_) and create a new one using a gutter icon over `main()` function.

Comment: The project consists of one file (main.go) in /home/pnunn/GolandProjects/awsomeProject.  The only other file in the directory is go.mod.  It all runs fine locally. I'll try deleting and re-creating.

Comment: Thanks a ton @s0xzwasd! I was losing my mind over this.